# Slider below the header without any spaces in ionic 3

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want to insert a slider just below the header(inside the ion-content). But I'm getting white space from the top, left and right as shown in the figure.

[image]

My HTML code for the slider is

```
 <ion-navbar color="river">

<ion-row>

      <ion-col width-10 style="text-align: right">
        <button ion-button icon-only (click)="shop();"  color="yel" clear end>
          <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col width-10 style="text-align: center">
        <button ion-button  icon-only (click)="product();"  color="yel" clear end>
          <ion-icon name="pricetag"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col width-10 style="text-align: left">
        <button ion-button  icon-only (click)="feedback();"  color="yel" clear end>
          <ion-icon name="md-chatbubbles"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

how can I avoid white space in between the header and the slider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be your ion-content like this `<ion-content padding></ion-content>`, Remove the padding and try . `<ion-content></ion-content>`